# How to set UIScrollView like 3D Square

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, uiimageview

I am working on Photo Editing App and I have 3 Scrollviews with UIImageview, I want to set ScrollViews as Below

[image]

I had Tried "**Scenekit**" but It won't work because I want ScrollableView.

Basically I want to create **3D collage**
Is there any other way to do this?

Is it Possible to set UIScrollView Like 3d Square?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Achieve this using **CATransform3D** using Following Code

I have created 3 Scrollview with UIImageview in StoryBoard

```
@IBOutlet var faces: [UIView]!
```

**ViewDidiLoad**

```
    var perspective: CATransform3D = CATransform3DIdentity
    perspective.m34 = -1.0 / 500.0

    self.view?.layer.sublayerTransform = perspective

    perspective = CATransform3DRotate(perspective, CGFloat(-Double.pi / 4), 1, 0, 0)
    perspective = CATransform3DRotate(perspective, CGFloat(-Double.pi / 4), 0, 1, 0)

    print(perspective)

    self.view.layer.sublayerTransform = perspective

    //add cube face 1
    var transform: CATransform3D = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 0, 50)
    addFace(0, withTransform: transform)

    //add cube face 2
    transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(50, 0, 0)
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, CGFloat(Double.pi / 2), 0, 1, 0)

    addFace(1, withTransform: transform)

    //add cube face 3
    transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, -50, 0)
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, CGFloat(Double.pi / 2), 1, 0, 0)

    addFace(2, withTransform: transform)
```

**addFace Function**

```
func addFace(_ index: Int, withTransform transform: CATransform3D) {
    let face: UIView? = faces[index]

    if let aFace = face {
        self.view.addSubview(aFace)
    }

    let containerSize: CGSize? = self.view.bounds.size

    face?.center = CGPoint(x: (containerSize?.width ?? 0.0) / 2.0, y: (containerSize?.height ?? 0.0) / 2.0)
    face?.layer.transform = transform
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you need to have the gestures to rotate the cube for adjusting the collage. So you can't go for UIKit only to achieve the same.

Converting from UIKit coordinates to SceneKit coordinates is what challenging in your requirement.

Instead, you need to make use of SceneKit as well as UIKit for the same to be done.

Follow the below steps

### Creating a cube UI using SceneKit

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mySceneView: SCNView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mySceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
    //Create instance of scene
    let scene = SCNScene()
    mySceneView.scene = scene
    //Add cube to scnview
    AddCubeToScene()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func AddCubeToScene()
{
    //Create a box of size 0.1 * 0.1 * 0.1
    let myBox = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)
    myBox.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    myBox.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
    //Create SCnnode of from geometry and specified its position
    let cubeNode = SCNNode(geometry: myBox)
    //Add created scnnode to scene
    mySceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cubeNode)
}
}
```

### Create a UIScrollView using UIKit

```
weak var scrollView: UIScrollView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect.zero)
scrollView.contentSize = contentSize
scrollView.delegate = self
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3
scrollView.indicatorStyle = .white
self.scrollView = scrollView

let clearContentView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentSize.width, height: contentSize.height))
    clearContentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    scrollView.addSubview(clearContentView)
    self.clearContentView = clearContentView
    clearContentView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "transform", options: .new, context: &ViewTransformChangedObservationContext)
    skView.addSubview(scrollView)
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    scrollView?.frame = view.bounds
    scene?.size = view.bounds.size
    if let scrollView = scrollView {
        adjustContent(scrollView: scrollView)
    }
}

func adjustContent(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let zoomScale = scrollView.zoomScale
    scene?.setContentScale(scale: zoomScale)
    let contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
    let contentSize = scrollView.contentSize
    let scrollAreaHeight: CGFloat = contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.height
    let yUIKit: CGFloat = contentOffset.y

    // Convert from UIKit coordinates to SpriteKit coordinates
    // UIKit has 0,0 in the top-left corner
    // SpriteKit has 0,0 in the bottom-left corner
    let ySpriteKit = scrollAreaHeight - yUIKit
    let contentOffsetSpriteKit = CGPoint(x: contentOffset.x, y: ySpriteKit)
    scene?.contentOffset = contentOffsetSpriteKit
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    adjustContent(scrollView: scrollView)
}

func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return clearContentView
}

func scrollViewDidTransform(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    adjustContent(scrollView: scrollView)
}

// scale between minimum and maximum. called after any 'bounce' animations
func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
    adjustContent(scrollView: scrollView)
}
```

Now add `UIScrollView` instances into each sides of the cube (i.e., childnodes)

You're there!

Answer (score 2):

The solution you are looking for could be as a framework.
You can take a look at these open source projects.
[MKCubeController](https://github.com/kmalkic/MKCubeController), [CubeController](https://github.com/nicklockwood/CubeController) and
[Gemini](https://github.com/shoheiyokoyama/Gemini).

CubeController is the one which is closest to your requirement, you may have to modify these a little bit.
Gemini also has cube implementation.

Comment: Hey, I think its all about Navigation. I didn't want to navigate it. I am Creating Photo Editing App so may be now you can Understand what I exactly want.